# Passing Guid to WCF service with NetDataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, netdatacontractserializer

I've created the contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [NetDataContract]
    void PassGuid(Guid id);

    [OperationContract]
    [NetDataContract]
    void PassInt(int id);
}
```

Attribute `NetDataContractAttribute` described [here](https://yoursrp.wordpress.com/2009/07/06/netdatacontractattribute).
When I'm calling `PassGuid` I get an error:

> Additional information: The formatter threw an exception while trying
>   to deserialize the message:  There was an error while trying to
>   deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:id.  The InnerException
>   message was 'XML 'Element' 'http://tempuri.org/:id' does not contain
>   expected attribute
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/:Type'.  The
>   deserializer has no knowledge of which type to deserialize.  Check
>   that the type being serialized has the same contract as the type being
>   deserialized.'.   Please see InnerException for more details.

But `PassInt` could be called with no errors.

Full source code [here](https://github.com/bonza/WcfNetDataContract).

Edited:
This question is not about efficiency of sending guids, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220135/wcf-how-to-send-guids-efficiently-not-as-strings), it is mostly about using NetDataContractSerializer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF - How to send GUIDs efficiently (not as strings)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220135/wcf-how-to-send-guids-efficiently-not-as-strings)

Comment: I have updated your github with [change](https://github.com/bonza/WcfNetDataContract/pull/1). `NetDataContractAttribute` class can be placed in shared class library to use in both client and server project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the custom serializer as `NetDataContractSerializer` at server side. The difference between the `NetDataContractSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer` is that the serialization adds additional information of Types.

E.g. 
`DatacontractsSerializer` serialized to:

```
<Customer xmlns="http://www.contoso.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <FirstName>Zighetti</FirstName>
  <ID>101</ID>
  <LastName>Barbara</LastName>
</Customer>
```

`NetDataContractSerializer` would serialize the same object to:

```
<Customer z:Id="1" z:Type="NetDCS.Person" z:Assembly="NetDCS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" xmlns="http://www.contoso.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
  <FirstName z:Id="2">Zighetti</FirstName>
  <ID>101</ID>
  <LastName z:Id="3">Barbara</LastName>
</Customer>
```

Inducing more type specific information.

In your case server knows about the `NetDataContractSerializer` but client doesn't. You have to share this behavior to the client by putting it in a shared code library. Then you can add this enw behavior to the client using below code:

```
       using (var client = new TestServiceClient())
        {
            // Get the channel factory
            var factory = client.ChannelFactory;

            // Attach the behavior
            foreach (OperationDescription desc in factory.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
            {
                DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dcsOperationBehavior = desc.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
                if (dcsOperationBehavior != null)
                {
                    int idx = desc.Behaviors.IndexOf(dcsOperationBehavior);
                    desc.Behaviors.Remove(dcsOperationBehavior);
                    desc.Behaviors.Insert(idx, new WcfClient.NetDataContractAttribute.NetDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(desc));
                    //return true;

                }
            }

            // pass
            client.PassInt(0);
            // fail
            client.PassGuid(Guid.NewGuid());
            client.Close();
        }
```

You can also use attach the behavior via configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that client-side autogenerated contract (see file `WcfClient\Service References\TestService\Reference.cs`) does not have `[NetDataContract]` attributes.

Therefore `DataContractSerializer` is used on the client side.

In order for `NetDataContractSerializer` to work on both client and server you will need to have proper contract definition on the client side (by referencing server DLLs or by extracting contract into separate DLL). And then you will have to create your own Proxy class (inherited from `ClientBase<ITestService>`) instead of autogenerated one (or just use `ChannelFactory<ITestService>` without any proxy classes at all).